# dynamically inserting meta description into php page

Tags: php

ok so I've created this website and want to convert it to php just for fun. The website structure looks like any 'normal' web structure. like this:-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

<body class="fish">
</body>
</html>
```

ok so i included from the `head` to the beginning of the body tag in `header.php` file. so header.php looks like this:- `

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

<body class="fish">`
```

now here is the problem. Each page should have it's own `title`, `body` class! and each page will also obviously have it's own meta description and content. How will I accomplish this guys? I was think of creating a function that base the meta description and body class on the page title. But is there a smatter way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Where is the meta description coming from?

Comment: Use a template system/engine and work with variables

Comment: @connor sorry error correct that for me. meta description in it's usual place at the head

Comment: @kingkero which template system/engine do you recommend?

Comment: Smarty, imho. Where are getting the meta description from? A variable? A database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a template engine or a MVC framework (such as CakePHP or CodeIgniter) which have template engines already incorporated in them.

Comment: lol I don't even remember when I posted this amateur question. Either way , even though I knew about MVC framework just wanted to mess with procedural php code. I think Laravel is by far my favorite.

Comment: Yeah, I would update my answer to list Laravel or Symfony - with Laravel being my favorite as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `header.php` do something like this:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $_tpl['title'] ?></title>
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $_tpl['meta_desc'] ?>">
</head>

<body class="<?php echo $_tpl['body_class'] ?>">
```

On your page, before you use `include('header.php')`, define the vars as follows:

```
$_tpl = array();
$_tpl['title'] = 'My Title';
$_tpl['meta_desc'] = 'My meta description.';
$_tpl['body_class'] = 'fish';
```

As others have said though, don't re-invent the wheel. You'd be better to investigate some of the already-established templating engines for PHP:

- [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)
- [RainTPL](http://www.raintpl.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating a template to do this if it will be dynamic. You have many options on how you with to pass the data, whether it be a database, an object, array, etc. It is really tough to generate the data based on the page title, unless you are using a very persistent format to title each page.

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?= $values['title'] ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?= $values['url'] ?>" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?= $values['image'] ?>/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?= values['name'] ?>"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOODP">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?= $values['image'] ?>" />
    <title><?= $values['title'] ?></title>
    <? if(isset($values['css'])) : ?>
    <? foreach($values['css'] as $css) : ?>
        <link href="/css<?= $css['data'] ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <? endforeach ?>
    <? endif ?>
    <? if(isset($values['js'])) : ?>
    <? foreach($values['js'] as $js) : ?>
        <script src="/js<?= $js['data'] ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <? endforeach ?>
    <? endif ?>
</head>
```